# How can I bulk Edit 400+ Domain's A Records managed by WHM? (Find A, replace with B)

Tags: whm

I have 400+ domains hosted by whm; and I need to find all A records of root domains (ie, example.com) and replace them with a new ip.

I do not need to change any records for CPANEL.example.com; those may remain the same.

Can I write a loop to replace all those domains, excluding subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to change IP of multiple domains without wasting time to changing each DNS record one by one then follow the work around

- Login to WHM
- On the left side there is a search box, there type Change IP OR find option under Multi Account function and click on Change Multiple Sites’ IP Addresses
- Then You will have all list of your domains, select domains you would like to swap IP address with then click on Change IPs of Selected Accounts
- Then It will ask you to select IP address from a drop down list, select IP address you would like to swap and click Change Ips
- Done!